# Sum of exponential decays with normally distributed lifetimes

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

If I have the sum

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N e^{-\frac{t}{\tau_i}}$$

where each $\tau_i$ is distributed normally with mean $\tau$, what will be the mean functional form of $f(t)$ in the large $N$ limit? Will it just be an exponential with lifetime $\tau$ i.e. $\langle f(t) \rangle =e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will absolutely not be an exponential with lifetime $\tau$; the exponential distribution is not one of the possible limiting distributions of a mean.

Since $\tau_i$ has non-zero density at 0, $1/\tau_i$ doesn't have a finite mean, and $\exp(-1/\tau_i)$ also doesn't have a finite mean. You'll get $f(t)\stackrel{p}{\to}\infty$.

This is clear in simulation when the distribution of $\tau$ is close enough to zero, eg

```
> summary(mean(exp(-1/rnorm(100000,4))))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
9.61e+36 9.61e+36 9.61e+36 9.61e+36 9.61e+36 9.61e+36 
> summary(mean(exp(-1/rnorm(100000,4))))
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
3.553e+39 3.553e+39 3.553e+39 3.553e+39 3.553e+39 3.553e+39 
> summary(mean(exp(-1/rnorm(100000,4))))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.7676  0.7676  0.7676  0.7676  0.7676  0.7676
```

The sample size needed for it to be clear that $f(t)\to\infty$ will increase very fast as $ \mu/\sigma$ for the Normal distribution increases, so with $\tau\sim N(0,10^2)$ it looks like the variance is finite and the asymptotic distribution is thus Normal by the central limit theorem. But it isn't and it's not.